# xUnit and Moq do not support async - await keywords

Tags: c#, moq, async-await, xunit.net

I am trying to discover how to apply the async and await keywords to my xUnit tests. I am using xUnit 1.9 and Async CTP 1.3. Here is my test case

I have an interface which specifies one asynchronous method call

```
public interface IDoStuffAsync
{
    Task AnAsyncMethod(string value);
}
```

I have a class which consumes the interface and calls the async method

```
public class UseAnAsyncThing
{
    private readonly IDoStuffAsync _doStuffAsync;

    public UseAnAsyncThing(IDoStuffAsync doStuffAsync)
    {
        _doStuffAsync = doStuffAsync;
    }

    public async Task DoThatAsyncOperation(string theValue)
    {
        await _doStuffAsync.AnAsyncMethod(theValue);
    }
}
```

In my tests I wish to check that the method `DoThatAsyncOperation` is calling the method with the correct value so I mock the interface and use the Moq to verify the call

```
    [Fact]
    public async void The_test_will_pass_even_though_it_should_fail()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IDoStuffAsync>();
        var sut = new UseAnAsyncThing(mock.Object);

        mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<string>()));

        await sut.DoThatAsyncOperation("test");

        // This won't throw a Moq.MockExcpetion so the test appears to pass
        // However it does not run
        mock.Verify(x => x.AnAsyncMethod("fail"));
    }
```

This test is using the `async` and `await` keywords. When it runs it erroneously passes as Moq should assert that the verify fails. Any code after the call to `sut.DoThatAsyncOperation("test");` does not run

```
    [Fact]
    public void This_will_work_and_assert_the_reslt()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IDoStuffAsync>();
        var sut = new UseAnAsyncThing(mock.Object);

        mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<string>()));

        sut.DoThatAsyncOperation("test").ContinueWith(y => { });

        // This won't throw a Moq.MockExcpetion so the test appears to pass
        // However it does not run
        mock.Verify(x => x.AnAsyncMethod("fail"));
    }
```

This test is setup without the await and async keywords and passes fine.

Is this expected behavior for xUnit and Moq?

---

**Update**

Thanks for Stephen's comment I managed to fix the first test by making two changes. The test now returns a Task instead of void and the Mock also returns a Task.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task The_test_will_pass_even_though_it_should_fail()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IDoStuffAsync>();
        var sut = new UseAnAsyncThing(mock.Object);

        mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnAsync(true);

        await sut.DoThatAsyncOperation("test");

        // This now fails as it should
        mock.Verify(x => x.AnAsyncMethod("fail"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Update paragraph above.  The TaskCompletionSource<T> was the key I was looking for in mocking my async method using MOQ.

Comment: Instead of explicitly creating a TaskCompletionSource you could simply use Task.FromResult:  

`mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));`

Comment: You can also use mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnAsync(true); to avoid setting up the task

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your unit test method to return `Task` instead of `void`, and it should work. Support for `async void` unit tests [is being considered for a future release](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9752).

I describe in detail [why async unit tests don't work by default](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html) on my blog. (My blog examples use MSTest, but the same problems existed in every other test runner, including xUnit pre-1.9).

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that also fails. This time is throws a NullRefException when running the mocked method. I guess the mock has to return a Task.

Comment: In fact that lead me to the answer. I can now get the test to pass by returning a TaskCompletionSource<bool> from the mock.

Comment: You can also use `Task.FromResult` as a shorthand for the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use the code from your 'Update', but it was stopping at the async method that I was mocking.

```
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    tcs.SetResult(default(T));


    mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(tcs.Task);
```

So to fix that I had to change the 'Return' method:

```
    mock.Setup(x => x.AnAsyncMethod(It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(()=> { return tcs.Task; } );
```