# Moq test passes even when verifying both Times.Once() and Times.Never() on same method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

I'm using `Xunit` to test the `Create` method on my `CarController` and I'm using `Moq` to mock my `CarRepository`.

I'm then using `mockCarRepository.Verify(m => m.Create(It.IsAny<Car>()), Times.Once());` to check that the `Create` method on my repository is being called.  However the test passes irrespective of whether I call it or not.

Here is a complete example where I verify `both that Create is called once AND that it is called never`.  My test passes when I would have expected it to fail.

```
using System;
using Moq;
using Xunit;
namespace Test
{
    public class CarTest
    {
        [Fact()]
        public async void CreateTest()
        {
            var mockCarRepository = new Mock<CarRepository>();
            var carController = new CarController(mockCarRepository.Object);
            carController.Create(new Car
            {
                Make = "Aston Martin",
                Model = "DB5"
            });
            mockCarRepository.Verify(m => m.Create(It.IsAny<Car>()), Times.Once());
            mockCarRepository.Verify(m => m.Create(It.IsAny<Car>()), Times.Never());
        }
    }

    public class CarController
    {
        private readonly CarRepository _repo;
        public CarController(CarRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public void Create(Car car)
        {
            _repo.Create(car);
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public virtual String Make { get; set; }
        public virtual String Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarRepository
    {
        public virtual void Create(Car car)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the test, although it still passes, I notice that the following exception is thrown:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Moq.MockException' occurred in Moq.dll

Additional information: 

Expected invocation on the mock should never have been performed, but was 1 times: m => m.Create(It.IsAny<Car>())

No setups configured.



Performed invocations:

CarRepository.Create(Test.Car)
```

The exception is expected as I am calling `Create` once and verifying `Times.Never()` but I would like my test to fail.  What do I need to do to achieve this?

**Update** It turns out that the problem was that I'd marked my test as `async` - removing that causes it to pass.  However the actual code I'm writing will call an `async` method, so my question is now, how can I verify methods are called when using asynchronous methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11232299/921321) for an explanation of why `async void` test methods do not work in xUnit.

The solution is to give your test method an `async Task` signature.

`async void` functionality has been added ready for version 2.0 of xunit, see [here](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9752) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the issue was that my test method was marked as `async` removing that causes it to work as expected.